# How to add Project Dependency DLL's when adding Project output in the Visual Studio installer?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installation, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm using `visual studio 2015`, `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer`. I'm creating the sample project for demonstrate my issue.

**Step1:** I'm creating the **SampleSetUpProject** in wpf Application.

**Step2:** Creating the **ClassLibrary1** Project and adding the **itextsharp** reference in that project.

**Step3:** I'm creating the **Setup1** Project in that application.  In Application Folder adding Project output, the dependency DLL  itextsharp not added in the Application folder. How to added the dependency dll adding project output?

**Step4 :** In application **output directory** my **DLL's** are there. But adding project output it's not added. If any possibilities are there for adding the Dependency dll's adding **Project output**?

Image for Adding Project output.[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saGyQ.png)

Comment: This works just fine when I try it.  Ensure that ClassLibrary1 actually uses a class from iTextSharp and that the WPF project actually uses ClassLibrary1.

Answer (score 0):

A setup can't know every one of your dependencies - for example there is nothing about a COM call that identifies a required Dll because the code references a GUID - so they need to be added manually. As your "Add" dialog shows, just add the Dlls (add file) and so on, to install to whichever location they are needed in. And another issue is that not all dependencies will be in the Application Directory - some (such as a shared COM Dll) need to be installed and registered in a common location. So some dependencies might be in Common Files, the GAC and so on.

Comment: I'm using "Add" dialog Adding Files. But Setup Project closing and reopening time, some DLL's are missing. Application output directory and Setup project missing DLL's comparison it's take long time. Any Solution for this issue?@PhilDW